# How can i make an input repeat itself if it does not receive a value?

Tags: python

**What is my problem?**

I am making an rpg game. My problem at the moment is that if you do not provide an input when naming your character (by pressing enter) your character does not receive a name.

> **what i want to be able to do:** to provide the user with another opportunity to re-enter their name

**My code for this segment of the game:**

```
print('\n > what should your hero be named?\n ')

name = input('> ') 

# i would need input to repeat here

time.sleep(1)
print(f'\n > welcome mighty hero! you shall be named: {name} !!!\n ')
print(' > a fine choice')
print('\n')
```

> please consider that i am a **beginner** and a solution that may seem obvious to you might not seem to be obvious to me

Comment: 1 print('\n > what should your hero be named?\n ')
     2 
     3 name = ""
     4 while not name:
     5     name = input('> ')
     6 
     7 # i would need input to repeat here
     8 
     9 time.sleep(1)
    10 print(f'\n > welcome mighty hero! you shall be named: {name} !!!\n ')
    11 print(' > a fine choice')
    12 print('\n')

Comment: Create a name = ''. then while not name, name = input('> ')